# List filenames and file paths of files in Mac side-by-side in Terminal

Tags: terminal, csv

Many posts discuss how to list paths and filenames separately. However, I need them both together. Is there a way to do that?

For example:

- Filename    Filepath
- A.xlsx      /Folder/Folder/A.xlsx
- B.xlsx /Folder/Folder/B.xlsx

Or even better if I can just output that to csv file as that is what I need in the end. One column filename. One column filepath

Answer (score 0):

If you have in file the paths you can extract the filename on this way:

```
for i in `cat filename`;
do
echo `basename $i`";"$i
done
```

Please clarify if you have list in file. If you do not have file you can run find command to search for files in particular tree. The first line should become:

```
for i in `find /path -type f -name "your_wildcard_here"`;
```

If you do not need to filter the files you must change the first line like this:

```
for i in `find /path -type f`;
```

where /path is the starting directory you want to search

Comment: i don't. I don't have the list in file

Comment: @forgodsakehold, please check my corrected answer if this is you search for

Comment: thank you. but i'd like to print every file and folder (recursively) in a specified folder. how do modify the code?

Comment: @forgodsakehold, if you need every file check my corrected andwer

Comment: Probably best to avoid a mixed `for i in $(find...)` in case of oddly named files, such as those with spaces. Just use one (`for i in **/*`) or the other (`find path -type f -printf '%f,%p\n'`).